# How to use autoescape off AND static variables inside django template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, tags

I'm using auto generated HTML which has been saved to a file and then read in again to use as part of a page in a django template.

In order to do this I have used:

```
{% autoescape off %}
  {{ my_html }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

However, in the `my_html` variable, I have some static content. This comes in the form of something like this:

```
<img src="{% static "img/tree_report.png" %}" width="12px" height="12px"/>
```

My issue is that the static content is not displayed. I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static 404 (in the browser error report)
```

I read something about `get_static_prefix` in another question but that doesn't solve my problem because I just get this instead:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20get_static_prefix%20%%7Dimg/tree_report.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I also tried endautoscape turning on and off periodically in `my_html` in the saved HTML variable.  That also didn't work.

Should I be autogenerating the development and production static files paths for `my_html` or is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Any suggestions are most welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: If I could lose the inverted commas around my html variable which is the default before using autoescape off then I wouldn't need to use autoescape off which would be another alternative but I don't know any way of doing this.

Comment: Try using `{{ my_html|safe }}` instead of putting `{% autoescape off %}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @user2556381, I was not aware of that possibility; however, unfortunately I still get: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Have you tried setting `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your `settings.py` file? And then add `{% load staticfiles %}` above all `link`s and `script`s

Comment: Naturally.  Normal static files which aren't embedded in the autoescape off variable work fine. FWIW I have this in settings.py: STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files') and in the template I have {% load static %} in the header.  I have another webapp which is already deployed which works fine with static files that this one is modelled on so I am sure that my static files config in general is fine.